# HTML parse special chars in Android

Tags: android, html, unicode

I have this simple problem: once I retrieve a mail text, sometimes it happens that `Html.fromHtml` cannot parse correctly the string.

I'll give you an example. This is the HTML string:

```
&amp;#‪8211‬;&amp;#‪8211‬;&amp;#‪8211‬;&amp;#‪8211‬;&amp;
```

It needs to be something like this:

–––––––––––––––––––––––––––

Is there a way in Android to achieve that? Do I need to use Regular Expressions?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the hidden characters (in this case) with:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll( "[\\u202C\\u202A]", "" );
```

After that it's just:

```
Html.fromHtml(myString);
```

And it will work in html context. Or if you want the real em dash characters:

```
Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(myString));
```

Demo of the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/CGzDc/ (javascript, you will have to use code in this answer for java)

Comment: the second part won't work, because the Html.fromHtml won't parse these special charachters, i already tried this. But the first works, i figured it out just 2 days ago. That's make yours answer the right one. Thanks

Comment: Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(myString)); worked for me. But Html.fromHtml accepts only String. So had to do
Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(myString).toString());

Answer (score 2):

The string in your example is HTML notation for `&#8211;&#8211;&#8211;&` (literally), so the correct browser behavior is to render it that way. For some reason that cannot be guessed from the description, some software has applied *double* encoding in the sense of first encoding the em dash “—” as `&#8211;` and then encoding the `&` again, as `&amp;`.

By the way, a sequence of consecutive em dashes may or may not produce a continuous line; this depends on the font. There are more reliable ways to producing long lines, such as the `<hr>` element and border properties in CSS.

Comment: That's right. Infact it's a big problem. The Html.fromHtml method correctly decode the &amp in &, but the dash code it's not decoded. Maybe by launching Html.fromHtml first from the main string it can convert the &amp, and after that i need something else to decode the &#8211 code.

Comment: @edoardotognoni since it's *double* encoded, you just need to call `Html.fromHtml` *twice*... `Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(myString))`

Comment: Btw, the string you gave is filled with [U+202C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm) and [U+202A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) after each `#`.. you should filter out those and the double decode will work

Comment: Yes, i was just thinking about that 2 minutes ago. How would you filter that?