# Converting string array to int

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm having a weird problem, trying to take a string from a string array
and convert it to an integer.
Take a look at this code snippet:

```
string date = "‎21/‎07/‎2010 ‏‎13:50";
var date1 = date.Split(' ')[0];
string[] dateArray = date1.Split('/');

string s = "21";
string t1 = dateArray[0];

bool e = string.Compare(s, t1) == 0;        //TRUE

int good = Convert.ToInt32(s);            //WORKING!
int bad = Convert.ToInt32(t1);  //Format exception - Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Can someone please explain why the conversion with s works, while with t1 fails?

Comment: may be I am missing something, why not try DateTime.Parse or .TryParse and do your logic?

Comment: Have you tried outputting what `t1` equals?

Comment: Do yourself a tremendous favor and learn to use the debugger. What is `t1` where it fails?

Comment: Did you mean this to say  `s` instead of `s1`: `int good = Convert.ToInt32(s1);` ?

Comment: It looks to me like `t1` will be "2010 13:50" when you try to parse it. `String#Compare` probably isn't doing what you think it should be doing.

Comment: t1 holds the same value as s.

Comment: @user1079266, I highly doubt that if you're getting a `Format Exception`

Comment: I don't believe its `WORKING!` because there's no actual `s1` change your `s` to `s1`.

Comment: @meustrus - Where are you getting that from? The OP is splitting twice. First on ` ` then on ``\`` (using the first result)

Comment: the better question is where is the OP getting that string from

Comment: I changed the code a little to remove the obvious from the table. I don't believe it myself, but it's actually not working for me. And @Jonathan, try to examine the code before attacking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your string is full of hidden characters, causing it to break. There's four [`U+200E`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) and one [`U+200F`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm)

Here's a clean string to try on:

```
string date = "21/07/2010 13:50";
```

Comment: @Oded In google chrome or firefox, open dev console and copypaste the op's string `"‎21/‎07/‎2010 ‏‎13:50".split("").map(function(v){return v.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)}).join(" ")` It's like a hex dump right in your browser. :P

Comment: @Oded - I just copy pasted it into Notepad++, and he's right!

Comment: Did similar in LinqPad: `"‎21/‎07/‎2010 ‏‎13:50".Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("X"))`

Comment: @Oded: Or just right click on it and select "Inspect Element" (in Chrome)... Can't say I thought of that before seeing Esailija's answer, though!

Comment: Wish I could +5 this, that's some out-of-the-box thinking!

Comment: Sure, but what made you look deeper?

Comment: @Oded I got InputFormatException when I tried bulletproof test code using the OP's string.

Comment: @Oded - He sensed a distrubance in the Force.

Comment: @Esailija, thank you very much! That is very impressive. I actually take this string from my images and movies metadata(using Shell32.dll)- I didn't know it can come with hidden characters...

Comment: I just came to the same result. I used this to test:


            `for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                int schar = s[i];
                int t1char = t1[i];
                if (schar != t1char)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                }
            }`

It broke on the first char.

Comment: @McAden yeah, this actually happens so often that I am wondering if I should make a chrome extension for looking up hidden bytes in questions (writing the .split("").map().join() gets tiresome even if you can do it in the browser). [This is the second time just today this happened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761534/html-parse-special-chars-in-android/13762633#comment18918034_13762633)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `string.Compare(s, t1) == 0` to test if the strings are equal? This overload of `Compare` does a *culture sensitive* comparison. But it doesn't mean that the strings are identical. To check if the strings consist of identical "sequences" of `char` values, use *ordinal* comparison. Ordinal comparison can be done, for example, with

```
bool e = s == t1;
```

In your case, the strings have different `Length`s, and they also differ on the first index, `s[0] != t1[0]`.

Your string `date` contains [right-to-left marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) and [left-to-right marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark). This may happen because you copy-paste from an Arabic text (or another language written in the "wrong" direction).

To remove these characters *in the ends* of your string (not in the middle), you can use something like

```
t1 = t1.Trim('\u200E', '\u200F');
```