# Using DateTime.ParseExact is throwing FormatExceiption

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I'm trying to use `DateTime.ParseExact`, but I keep getting an error thrown back

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Looking at the screenshot below, I've stored my item in the `dateToParse` variable (just for reference purposes).

but at the bottom, where I'm trying to set the `Date`, it doesn't want to play nicely.

```
Date = DateTime.ParseExact(rawDescription[4], "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy", null)
```

I also tried it without the single quotes and with a specified culture

```
Date = DateTime.ParseExact(rawDescription[4], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

[image]

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: What culture are you running this under? Are you sure it uses / as a date separator?

Comment: rawDescription is a `string[]`

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact("03/27/2011", "MM/dd/yyyy", null);` works fine for me, perhaps your error is somewhere else?

Comment: Could there be invisible characters in your string? A good way to check is to check the `Length`.

Comment: @James *"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."* I should hope not.

Comment: the `double.parse()` is not the issue, because when I set `Date = null`, the code continues to work as expected.

Comment: @KendallFrey sorry I'm on my mobile cant see the actual exception just the code :( have you tried using Invariant culture whilst parsing?

Comment: @KendallFrey you were right, there was an invisible character in the date string. running `rawDescription[4].Trim();` worked it out.

Comment: There's a space character before the first date's character.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell actually looking at your watch value your date *does* have a white space character at the start of your date.

Comment: yup, that's what I said 3 comments above. Thanks for spotting it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var dateToParse = rawDescription[4];` is showing a space before the first character. Adding a call to `Trim` will fix the issue.

```
Date = DateTime.ParseExact(rawDescription[4].Trim(), "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: I would be tempted to delete the question the issue was invalid data so *technically* there wasn't a problem, the code was functioning as expected

Comment: That space is so hard to see, even when you know about it.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely looked at it a number of times before posting the question. It's hard to see, that's for sure. I didn't pick up on it until I ran `rawDescription[4].length` and saw it was `11` when it's supposed to be `10`

Comment: @James *technically* there was a problem. The problem was that `DateTime.ParseExact` cannot parse invalid characters ` `.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell your saying that like you were *trying* to parse invalid characters though - which you weren't (at least not intentionally). It's the equivalent of saying "*Theres a problem with `Int32.Parse` it won't parse '1oo'*". The function failed because it was being misused and the exception clearly explains that. The reason I said you should delete was because I can't see this answer helping people in the future - however, that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an invariant culture for the format provider, not null:

```
Date = DateTime.ParseExact(rawDescription[4], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting a working answer.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I tried that as well... tried both ways. PS: downvote isn't mine.

Comment: And this hasn't worked for you? That's very strange as it should work.

Comment: for some odd reason, no dice.

Comment: someone is down voting all the responses here

Comment: @Sorceri No I just downvoted this answer as the OP said, I won't work.

Comment: Then I guess that the problem is in some other portion of your code because `DateTime.ParseExact(rawDescription[4], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` should always work if `rawDescription[4]` is a `string` and equals `03/27/2011`.

Comment: @L.B, and why do you think that it won't work? Any arguments behind this statement?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov `for some odd reason, no dice. – Chase Florell` and I tried it as well.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell, what is `rawDescription[4]`? Is it a `string` type?

Comment: Provider can be null *If provider is null, the CultureInfo object that corresponds to the current culture is used.

Comment: rawDescription is a `string[]`, therefore `rawDescription[4]` is a `System.String`

Comment: Alright, so what you are telling me is that `DateTime.ParseExact("03/27/2011", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` is throwing a `FormatException`? That's pretty hard to believe. I am really sorry but I don't buy this :-) `DateTime.ParseExact("03/27/2011", "MM/dd/yyyy", null);` could of course throw this exception based on your current thread culture.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, looks like my "code" was right other than an invisible character within`rawDescription[4]`. All I had to do was `.Trim();`

Comment: @ChaseFlorell, no your code is not right. Other than removing wrong characters from your string you need to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` if you want your code to work on all cultures. Otherwise your code might break if the current thread culture is not compatible with this datetime format. That's why I posted my answer. For example try setting your current thread culture to `de-DE` and you will see how nicely your code breaks if you do not specify an invariant culture.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I am using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. The `null` bit was in the screenshot during some ["brute force debugging"](http://www.icodeguru.com/dotnet/debugging-strategies-for-.net-developers/8217final/LiB0015.html).

Comment: Well unfortunately when you posted your question I couldn't know this because yo didn't specify it. You edited your question later. Anyway, glad you could find the problem and solve the issue.

Comment: +1 for specifying that setting the appropriate CultureInfo will bode well for the next guy that tries to use `null`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a leading whitespace character in your string, as in `" 03/27/2011"`. That's seen before.

Your string might also contain invisible characters, like left-to-right marker or non-breaking zero-width space, or whatever they're all called. We've [seen that before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770105) on Stack Overflow.

What does `rawDescription[4].Length` return? Try inspecting the `char` one by one, as in `rawDescription[4][0]`, `rawDescription[4][1]`, and so on.

Answer (score -3):

You need to put rawDescription[4] in to a string and pass the string to the method.

Comment: Why the down vote?  Can you tell me what data type rawDescription[4] is?  Can you confirm that it will parse to a string when passed to the method?  Hence, Put it in a string and pass it.

Comment: I would say because your answer doesn't help in the slightest, it's already being passed as a string, it's being indexed from the array.

Comment: @james  he did not specify at the time what the data type was. I will nit pick your posts too then ;)