# TextView: Some of the unicode characters are not rendered

Tags: android, unicode

I am trying to render a simple bullet on my TextView. Here is my code

```
private static final String DOT = "\u26ab"; //"\u2b24";

helloWorld = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
helloWorld.setText(Html.fromHtml("hi <h1 style='display:inline'>" + DOT+ "</h1> here"));
```

The unicode character `\u2b24` is not rendered correctly below API level 23. 
The character `\u26ab` is rendered correctly however on all API levels.

Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: did you tried this?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13770493/706833 (double encoding)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static final String DOT = "&#8226;"; // Bullet
```

Check this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_(typography)) or this [page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26ab/index.htm) for other resources.

```
//Java --> Html
\u26ab == &#9899;
\u2b24 == &#11044;
```